# How does Double.isNaN() work?

Tags: java, floating-point, double, nan

The sun jdk implementation looks like this:

```
return v != v;
```

Can anyone explain how that works?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NaN values are not equal to anything (if one side of an equality is NaN, the equality is false), so NaN != NaN. Obviously every normal double does equal itself

Answer (score 4):

A nan is the only double that is not equal to itself. Thus, checking v!=v will only produce True for NaN.

Here is what the [Java spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html) has to say:

> Floating-point operators produce no
>   exceptions (§11). An operation that
>   overflows produces a signed infinity,
>   an operation that underflows produces
>   a denormalized value or a signed zero,
>   and an operation that has no
>   mathematically definite result
>   produces NaN. All numeric operations
>   with NaN as an operand produce NaN as
>   a result. **As has already been
>   described, NaN is unordered, so a
>   numeric comparison operation involving
>   one or two NaNs returns false and any
>   != comparison involving NaN returns
>   true, including x!=x when x is NaN.**